# angular *ngIf not working in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm opening a modal in angular when a button is pressed like that:

```js
const activeModal = this.modalService.open(SelectEventModalComponent, {});
```

Now I'm setting the variable `init` to true when the `SelectEventModalComponent` inits.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-select-event-modal',
  templateUrl: './select-event-modal.component.html',
})
export class SelectEventModalComponent implements OnInit {
  init = false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.init = true;
  }
}
```

and in the html I display the value of init and TRUE, if init is also true.

```html
<p>{{ init }}</p>
<p *ngIf="init">TRUE</p>
```

I now expect to get true and TRUE in the ui however I get this:

[image: true but not TRUE]

It seems like that *ngIf, *ngFor, etc. are not getting rendered properly when I use them in modals. Is this a bug, intentional or am I missing something out?

Comment: Can you create a  minimal reproducible example? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What kind of modal are you using? If you're using ng-bootstrap, work (see the forked stackblitz,https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdw2sd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodal-component.ts if you're using another modal library, please edit the question indicate what library are you using